# stop WhatsApp duplicating images sent with the camera

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

At least on my device (Galaxy S6) whenever I send a picture or video on WhatsApp using the camera, the following happens:

- A low quality version is stored under WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/Sent
- A higher resolution version is stored in WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images

The same happens with videos under WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video.
In some cases as well, sending pictures from another media source puts them all in "/WhatsApp Images" rather than on the Sent folder.

Every now and then I like to move all the media to my pc/back it up online, sort it on folders etc, which becomes a real pain due to this fact. I.e I want to keep the higher res. versions, then I must first identify them from the "received" folder (for things I send.. why not put them in /Sent??) then delete the low res. versions.

With already a few years on the market and its value you'd expect an app of this magnitude to have a significant team of developers behind, then it's almost unbelievable that such a mess is created by this app.

Am I missing something here, some issue with my device/settings, or does the app just suck at this?